# Complex SQL to LINQ in C#

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I'm completely newbie in LINQ and Lamda expressions.
I have a bit complex SQL statement that retrieves information from several database tables:

```
SELECT A.OrderID, A.FORMJDENO, A.Title, B.Descr, C.Code, C.Descr, D.ModificationDate from OrderForm A 
LEFT JOIN OrderPriority B ON A.OrderPriorityID = B.OrderPriorityID 
LEFT JOIN StockClass C ON A.StockClassID = C.StockClassID 
LEFT JOIN AuditTrailLog D ON A.OrderID = D.ObjectID 
WHERE D.ColumnInfoID= 487 AND D.OldValue='1' AND D.NewValue='2' AND A.FormStatus=2 AND A.FormType=3 AND B.OrderPriorityID=1000001 AND C.StockClassID=1000002
AND A.DeptID IN 
    ( SELECT DeptID FROM Department WHERE InstID = 1000006 )
AND DATEDIFF(m,D.ModificationDate, A.VendorDeliveryDate) >= 3
```

I already have the LINQ almost done, using `.Contains()` method replacing the `WHERE...IN` SQL clause, but i need some help to make de `joins` restricting the results basing on values that belongs to other tables and using `DATEDIFF` equivalent in LINQ.
This is what I already have got and is working fine, but obviously it is no restricting the results like the above SQL statement. I tried several ways with no success. I need the equivalent LINQ

**UPDATE:**

Finally I was able to get it working. This is the final LINQ that retrieves the same records than the SQL statement. Many thanks to @Gert Arnold:

```
var valid = dba.OrderForm
            .Where(q => q.FormType == 3
                        && q.FormStatus == 2
                        && q.OrderPriority.OrderPriorityID == orderpriorityID
                        && q.StockClass.StockClassID == stockclassID
                        && dba.AuditTrailLog.Where(log => q.OrderID==log.ObjectID)
                                .Any(log => log.ColumnInfoID == 487
                                            &&  log.OldValue == "1"
                                            && log.NewValue == "2"
                                            && EntityFunctions.DiffMonths(log.ModificationDate,     
                                                                 q.VendorDeliveryDate) >= period)
                        && departments.Contains(q.DeptID));
```

Comment: Linq-to-Entities? And what is the multiplicity of the association OrderForm - AuditTrailLog?

Comment: Yes Linq to Entities, I am developing a MVC ASP.NET project under Visual C#. The multiplicity OrderForm-AuditTrailLog is 1.N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is about it:

```
dba.OrderForm.Where(q => q.FormType == 3 
    && q.FormStatus == 2   
    && q.OrderPriority.OrderPriorityID == 1000001
    && q.StockClass.StockClassID == 1000002
    && q.AuditTrailLogs
        .Any(log => log.ColumnInfoID == 487
                 && log.OldValue == "1"
                 && log.NewValue == "2"
                 && EntityFunctions.DiffMonths(log.ModificationDate, 
                                                 q.VendorDeliveryDate) >= 3)
    && departments.Contains(q.DeptID));
```

I assume you've got (or can create) a navigation property `OrderTable.AuditTrailLogs`.

Without navigation property you can use

```
&& dba.AuditTrailLogs.Where(log => q.OrderID == log.ObjectID).Any(...
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @Gert Arnold. Your code looks good but i cannot test it due to I haven't `OrderForm.AuditTrailLogs` navigation property. How can I create it?

Comment: That depends, code-first, database-first. But that would be a different topic. You can do without, please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks @Get Arnold .I use your piece of code without using navigation property, but VS2010 is underlining  `&& log.OldValue == "1"` warning that operator `&&` cannot be applied to operators of type `int`and `bool`. Data type for this column at database is varchar(4000). Any idea?

Comment: Also I think you mean `AuditTrailLog` instead `AuditTrailLogs` when you talk about use it without navigation property. Right?

Comment: Ah, little typo. AuditTrailLog or AuditTrailLogs depends on the name of the DbSet in your context, probably the former.

Comment: Ok don't worry @Gert Arnold I've made a small modificatiosn to your suggested code. Now is fetching rows but not sure if is the correct LINQ. Could you please take a look at my first post update? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks good. You can use variables, no problem. Of course you're the one to judge whether it's the correct data!

Comment: Thanks @Gert Arnold . After some tests I can assure that it is fetching the same records :)